# Can we create a stored procedure to copy detached .mdf and .ldf files from original location to new location?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a script to attach database, move .mdf and .ldf files to new location and then attach the database. I created a stored procedure to detach and attach the database. Can I get a suggestion as to how I can move the files from the script itself?

```
Use master;
Go
Create procedure User_sp_detach_attach
    @db_name varchar(max),
    @new_mdf_path varchar(max),
    @new_ldf_path varchar(max)
As
Set NoCount On;
declare @db_id smallint;
declare @mdf_file varchar(max);
declare @ldf_file varchar(max);
declare @ori_mdf nvarchar(max);
declare @ori_ldf nvarchar(max);
declare @new_mdf_file nvarchar(max);
declare @new_ldf_file nvarchar(max);
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @db_id=DB_ID(@db_name);
set @mdf_file=@db_name+'.mdf';
set @ldf_file=@db_name+'_log.ldf';
select @ori_mdf=physical_name from sys.master_files where database_id=@db_id and file_id=1;
select @ori_ldf=physical_name from sys.master_files where database_id=@db_id and file_id=2;
set @new_mdf_file=@new_mdf_path+'\'+@mdf_file;
set @new_ldf_file=@new_ldf_path+'\'+@ldf_file;
print 'New location of .mdf file: '+@new_mdf_file;
print 'New location of .ldf file: '+@new_ldf_file;
EXEC sp_detach_db @db_name;
--Move files
Set @sql='CREATE DATABASE ' + @db_name + ' ON (FILENAME=''' + @new_mdf_file + '''), (FILENAME=''' + @new_ldf_file + ''') FOR ATTACH;'
Print @sql;
Exec (@sql);
Print 'Moved and attached successfully';
Go
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are doing detach/attach?  Why not just take a backup, copy the files and restore it elsewhere?  Assuming you are running 2005 (Enterprise) or higher, you'll get backup compression also, which will help if the DBs are large.

Comment: Ugh, please listen to @Kris. Use backup and restore. Detach and attach is like changing a flat tire while you're still moving.

Comment: I have to do this when I run out of space on a particular drive. So I add a new drive on the same server, detach the database, move the files to the new drive and attach the database.

Comment: If you are doing this that frequently you need to seriously reconsider how you allocate drive space. This should be a once a GREAT while, not something you do so frequently you need a procedure for.

Comment: We have many servers. Each server with hundreds of database. Attach and detach is the fastest way for us to manage this move. I just wanted to know if it is possible to incorporate all the steps in a single sp/batch file/powershell script.

Comment: If you used shared storage (*sigh*) then yes, attach/detach is indeed the fastest way to move it.

Comment: Found an alternative. Using backup and then restore with move option.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `xp_cmdshell`, write (or find and use) a CLR routine to do file copies and things like that. For example, the unrecomnended use of `xp_cmdshell`.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell "COPY \\share\path\file.mdf \\othershare\otherpath\file.mdf"
```

However, you would be better just making a backup (which from SQL Server 2008 R2 supports compressed backups) and you will get a faster transfer than detaching and copying files.  Not to mention the risks of detaching a file and not being able to reattach.

Recommendation: Use `BACKUP` and `RESTORE`.

Comment: Alternatively, he could use `MIRROR TO DISK = 'C:\backupsgohere'` in his backup syntax as xp_cmdshell does open up a few security holes.